# gpg signing support for JGIT

Tags: git, gnupg, jgit

I am using jgit for automation and I would like to ask if gpg signing is available on jgit. I haven't found an implementation yet on the net.

If it still not available, can you recommend an implementation to automate gpg signing for git?

Answer (score 5):

[JGit has a task for implementing signed commits](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382212). Most of that, but at least the tasks dependency of a cryptography provider is also necessary for signed tags.

I'd suggest you execute git as a new process to amend an existing commit with a signature or to create a new tag with a signature. JGit has no problems with commits or tags created that way.

(Note: Obtaining security by automated creation of a signature, that you wouldn't have without the signature, is unlikely.)